# jquery ui draggable stop function on clone

Tags: jquery, user-interface, clone, draggable

i have 2 lists, one draggable(#object) and one sortable(#target).
i would like to drag a clone to the sortable list and then do some things to the clone once it is in the sortable list.

i've got something up on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d8nieldonaldson/smYeh/3/

here's some of the code:

```
$("#object li").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#target",
    opacity: 0.5,
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    stop: function(e , ui) {
        ui.helper.css("width" , "140px");
    }
});
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resizing the `li` element and not the `img`!
Anyway, even doing so will resize the helper (using `stop`) but when inserted the element to the list it'll return to the original, so I've modified the code and added animate to a better user experience ;-) :

```
(function($) {

    $("#target").sortable({
        revert: true,
        update: function(e, ui) {
            if (ui.item.hasClass('ui-draggable')) ui.item.find('img').animate({
                width: "140px"
            })
        }
    });
    $("#object li").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#target",
        opacity: 0.5,
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $("ul, li").disableSelection();
})(window.jQuery);
```

[Example link](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/smYeh/5/).